# error establishing a database connection 3

Tags: database, errors

This error has already been faced by a lot of people, but I could not find an answer in my case. 
My wordpress website works perfectly in local

What I have done:

- Upload with filezila
- Create a sql database in OVH
  -Import all the SQL tables from local to the website with phpmyadmin
- Modify the wp-config.php file and also the wp-config-sample.php writting my informations.

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: Right now it's a localhost link. Do I need to change with the real website name?

Comment: Just tried to modify siteurl and home in the wp_options with the real website name. But it didn't work.

Comment: Can you change the name `wp-config.php` and enter the DB credentials in the installation wizard to see if it will connect? Don't finish installation, just check DB connection.

Comment: I already modified the wp-config but it didn't work, I get this error. Maybe the localhost is wrong though. The host is OVH. I tried mysql5-21.

Comment: I modified the localhost in wp-config.php , and now, I don't have the same error, but a: 504 gateway time out

Comment: I wrote a test.php with a "hello" message, and when I do www.mywebsite.fr/test.php , I can see the "hello"

Comment: Maybe this [OVH thread](https://community.ovh.com/t/error-establishing-a-database-connection-wordpress/6154/8) will be helpful

Comment: Already checked this link but it didn't help me :/

Comment: DB address is not a `localhost`, but e.g. `{something}.mysql.db`, `mysql5-6.perso`.  `mysql5-21` is full server name?

Comment: mine is: ftp.cluster021.hosting.ovh.net

Comment: Check `mysql5-21.mysql.db`. From [docs.ovh.com](https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/hosting/managing-a-database-on-a-web-hosting-package/#cant-connect-to-local-mysql):  MySQL (on shared hosting) does not work locally but on the network. You may have incorrectly put localhost in your script configuration. Instead you have to enter `name_of_your_db.mysql.db` as the server name in your website’s configuration file.

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by website's configuration file? Which file?

Comment: It's a quote. Put `mysql5-21.mysql.db` (I assume mysql5-21 is name of your database) in `wp-config.php` as DB host address.

Comment: I did it, and now I get the same error as the beginning

Answer (score 0):

I too had faced the same issue many times but after refreshing the browser it solved my problem.

Kindly check the wp-config file and verify if the database name and other information is correct.

Another thing you can try is restarting your local host.

Comment: I've already done all this but thx

Comment: Are you in the initial development stage or you already have had developed the site.

Comment: initial development !!

Comment: Did you try reinstalling by creating a separate database